# Adding space after a line in ToC

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, tocloft

I have been trying to determine way to add space **after** a section or chapter line in my table of contents. `tocloft` allows me to add spacing before lines but not after, and this leads to spacing issues at the top of new pages (see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119347/conditional-spacing-in-toc-column-headers)).

I have tried using \preto and \appto commands, *e.g.*,

```
\preto\section{
  \addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 2pt}
}
\appto\section{
  \addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 5pt}
}
```

However, `\appto` causes errors (for reasons explained in [another TeX.SX post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75184/how-to-append-code-to-a-section)). I also tried manually adding the ToC line:

```
\usepackage{nameref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\currentname}{\@currentlabelname}
\makeatother

\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}

\preto\section{
  \addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 2pt}
  \addtocontents{toc}{
    \protect\contentsline{section}{\numberline{\thesection}\currentname}{}
  }
  \addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 5pt}
}
```

This also didn't work as it used the previous section name rather than the current section name (since it is called in `\preto` not `\appto`). This attempt also causes problems with `hyperref`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add space after a sectional unit entry you can redefine the corresponding `\cftXafterpnum` command; for example, to add `10pt` after chapter entries:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\par\addvspace{10pt}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}
\section{Test Section}
\section{Test Section}
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}
\section{Test Section}
\section{Test Section}

\end{document}
```

[image]